# What does the callback type refer to in regard to array_map()?

Tags: php, functional-programming

For years I've been biting bullets attempting to write functional code in PHP with hacks like this:

```
class Foo {
    function addOne($wu) {
        return $wu + 1;
    }
    function getBiggerThings(array $things) {
        $that = $this;
        return array_map(function ($i) use ($that) {
            return $that->addOne($i);
        }, $things); 
}
```

Today a colleague pointed out that I could write:

```
return array_map(array($this, 'addOne'), $things);
```

I can't find any documentation on this on php.net. Am I reading the [callback type documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) incorrectly?

Comment: Look here instead: http://php.net/language.types.callable - it's all documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to highlight the following from [commented PHP docs](http://php.net/language.types.callable):

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

This actually is since a pretty long time, so to say before PHP 5.3 which allowed you the anonymous function "workaround".

Comment: What a superb example of why you shouldn't use passive case in English. I read this as "this is what PHP does for you".

Comment: Yes I've have been reading somewhere that it is bad style if you explain something, however I'm not totally immune to make the same mistake so I won't flame the manual right now ;) - If you like, you can edit the manual page and improve it suggesting a patch. There is a link in the top-right corner to edit it.

Answer (score 4):

This is documented in [the documentation about the Callable type](http://php.net/types.callable)

Comment: Not downvoting because it's my question and I appreciate the answer, but [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: @kojiro well, you asked for a link, not for an example or explaination of the docs...

Comment: I asked *where it was documented*, which is not the same as asking for a link. In fact, I had already read that page, and hadn't understood the answer that was written there (for the reason I described in @hakre's answer). It took him calling out the actual sentence for me to realize that sentence was describing what I asked about.

Comment: Well, if you don't understand the text, you should take a look at the examples. You can see this PHP feature in type 2 and 3 of example #1.